# Firebase hosting for .NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, firebase, webforms, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a Web Forms app using the Firebase. I know it offers the SDK for .NET Framework 4.5+ and I'm using [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=en#c) to set it up. I managed to run the hosting and access the page, where it can navigate among the HTML files within the `public` directory. I moved the .aspx (and .aspx.cs) files into the public directory and redeployed, but the .aspx page is displayed like a text file with all the `<%: property %>` tags printed as is. See screenshot below using the Wingtip Toys sample from Microsoft documentation.

I'm lost whether firebase doesn't support .aspx, I set up something wrong, or if the documentation lacks important information.

[image: View of the .aspx page as displayed with the firebase]

Comment: Are .NET Web Forms static? Firebase hosting can only deploy static websites from their CDN. If you're looking to deploy a dynamic/server-side-rendered application, you'll need to look at GCP's App Engine, AWS Beanstalk etc.

Comment: The documentation link you are referring is for the Firebase Admin SDK, which is intended for server-side. Firebase Hosting by itself is for static content, and client-side applications (SPA, PWA). To serve dynamic content with Firebase Hosting using C#, you need to use the [integration with Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run).